# SQL Agent Error 0xC0100037 - SSIS SQL Services Integration Services

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssis, ssms, azure-sql-managed-instance

It's been days that I get a SQL job error:

```
Executed as user: DB8C0\WF-bFkfnwG44FCe3pF. 
Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  
Version 15.0.2195.176 for 64-bit  Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft. All rights reserved.    
Started:  10:54:32 PM  Package execution on IS Server failed. 
Execution ID: 7705, Execution Status:6.  
To view the details for the execution, right-click on the Integration Services Catalog, and open the [All Executions] report  Failed to execute IS server package because of error 0xC0100037. 
Server: tcp:localhost,11000, 
Package path: \SSISDB\ETL\DLC_DWH_SSIS\00_InitFacts.dtsx, 
Environment reference Id: 1.  
Started:  10:54:32 PM  
Finished: 11:05:54 PM  Elapsed:  682.079 seconds.  
The package execution failed.
```

On the second attempt the job finishes successfully, but I cannot find any explanation on this particular error that keeps happening every night.
The job are scheduled on a SQL managed instance on Azure platform.
Do you have any idea or experience to fix that?
Thanks.

Comment: You mentioned "this particular error" but, as the message says, the "particular error" isn't shown here. It will be shown in the execution history report in the integration services catalog. Find your error there.

Comment: The error code you have quoted maps, appropriately, to a StackOverflowException. Do you have a script task in your SSIS package?